# Is there a "bending rigidity index" of some sort for semi-rigid aluminum ducts?

Tags: hvac, dryer, ducts

Some semi-rigid aluminum ducts bend easily and others do not.  I want to purchase semi-rigid aluminum ducts online of a specific bending rigidity/stiffness that minimizes sagging but can be easily bent for corners.  For different applications, I may want more rigid ducts or less rigid ducts.

If there is not a "rigidity index" of some sort, then is there a way to estimate rigidity using other specifications such as metal thickness, etc.

Thank you,